# Unrestricted height thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have set my default thumbnail size in settings > media, however as I see it you *Have* to add a value. However, I'd like to specify a width, but allow for an unrestricted height. For instance, both these dimensions would be alright:

```
w: 120px h: 70px
w: 120px h: 240px
```

Doesn't Wordpress allow this behaviour? Or should we simply set the height value to a ridiculously high number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) you can do something like that with `width` but I imagine it works the same with `height`:

> **$width**
>
> (int) (optional) The post thumbnail width in pixels. **Set to 9999** to resize based on $height
>   Default: 0

Really I think you would want to set it to something ridiculously high which 9999 should work for you. You could test this and use a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to try it out or revert your changes if it doesn't work.